# What is the antonym of "installation"?

Tags: word-choice

From Dictionary.com, *uninstall* is a word, but *uninstallation* is not.  I tried *deinstallation* and that isn't a word as well.  Is there any word equivalent, ending in -tion that *is* a real word?

Comment: It's probably not an official word due to lack of usage. "Uninstallation" seems to be [good enough for Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308233) though.

Comment: I suggest the only reason OP thinks *uninstallation* and *deinstallation* aren't words is because he's looking in the wrong place. Even [NGrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=uninstallation%2Cdeinstallation&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) has a couple of thousand usages; I'm sure there are far more than that *every day* across the internet - rarely misunderstood or bothersome to the readers.

Comment: There exist more dictionaries (and certainly more authoritative ones) than *dictionary.com*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think a good antonym for "installation" is "removal". It doesn't end in *-tion*, but it is a clear word which refers to taking something out. (On the other hand, installing is putting something in.)

Interestingly, **uninstall** is only used in a computer science context.

Comment: +1 to you for pointing out that many things you can *install* aren't *uninstalled*, they're *removed*. -1 to OP for saying *uninstallation* isn't a word.

Answer (score -2):

Since you want a word which ends in *-tion*, how about *extraction*?

First you install an immobiliser. If the unit is faulty, you could *extract* the immobiliser for repair or replacement.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes the situation calls for both a "deinstallation" or "deconstruction" and removal.  In the case of disengaging something large or connected to a structure that must be dismantled prior to removal from the site.  Such as a set of bleachers, they must first be uninstalled, dismantled, or deconstructed, and then the material removed.  I, too, was looking for that word.  If it becomes so cumbersome as to take more than a few minutes, I'll stick with the previous words.